# PHP array of numbers with range() and foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, range

I have a really strange problem with range();
According to docs :

```
Create an array containing a range of elements
```

But when I do :

```
foreach (range(900,950,1) as $art_id){
    //ob_start();
    //do stuff
    //do a lot more stuff
    echo $art_id;
    //ob_get_clean(); }
```

or even

```
$arts_id = range (900, 920);
 foreach ($arts_id as $art_id){
        //ob_start();
        //do stuff
        //do a lot more stuff
        echo $art_id;
        //ob_get_clean(); }
```

The output is strangly repeating itself in a series like

`"900,900,901,900,901,902,900,901,9002,903,900..."`

meaning it is comming back to the first ID after each loop.

```
(1st iteration -> 900
2nd iteration -> 900,901
3rd iteration -> 900,901,902
...)
```

When I just put a manual array it works perfectly in order and no duplicates :

```
$arts_id = array(900,901,902,903,904,905,906,907,908,909,910...);
```

What Am I doing wrong (again ?? )

**EDIT I**

here is the whole script :

http://pastebin.com/ZHm3ub6n

It is actually a slightly modified version of the slashdot scraping example included in the [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) script . Nothing special.

It is executed inside WP but OUTSIDE the loop ..

Comment: The 3rd parameter is `step` and its default value is `1`, so it is not necessary to use it in your case.

Comment: @fedorqui , Thanks . I know , in fact the second example I do not use it . I was just checking why it fails ..

Comment: I have also been checking and the performance is OK in all cases given. Aren´t you nesting different `foreach` or changing values inside the loop? Otherwise it sounds very strange.

Comment: @fedorqui - yep .. a lot of nesting :-) see update for whole script

Comment: There's no appreciable difference between `range()` and a manual array with the same contents.

Comment: @Jack, I understand there should not be . but how to explain this problem when executing the code ?

Comment: Well, can you create a reproducible test case using codepad?

Comment: @jack difficult , I can not include libraries in codepad. I can however, show you a live one on a server , but it will be of not much help.. You can try to execute my code from the pastebin ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be in the rest of your code, because this works fine.
please share more of the script.

It looks like the foreach is nested within a similair foreach,

```
 $arts_id = range (900, 920);
 foreach ($arts_id as $art_id){
    foreach (range (900,$art_id) as $art_id2){
        echo $art_id2."<br/>";
    }
 }
```

This produces an output you've described

**EDIT**

Personally i'd add the the function scraping_slashdot a reset of the variable $ret just in case.

for example:
$ret = array();

Currently the echo of $output is within the loop, which creates an output like the following:

```
Article 1
Article 1, Article 2
Article 1, Article 2, Article 3
etc.
```

place echo  $output outside the loop, or $ouptut = ''; inside the loop.

Comment: I already spotted the echo thing and got it out . It was only debug.. But the loop is really executing multiple times (insert post) and i do not understand why a manual insert of the array will not duplicate also with the echo in the same place ..

Comment: If the echo is the problem, why a manual array insert does not give duplicated results ?

Comment: of course ! `$ret = array();` should bethe right answer .. the `scraping_slashdot` is adding to array without resetting it . so it is adding to it on each iteration. I still have to verify , but it looks like it is correct. Not an echo or nesting problem. still it will not answer why with manual array insert it works OK...